# Java Vector Thread safety

Tags: java, vector, thread-safety

Is there any danger, if im using one Vector(java.util.Vector) on my server program when  im accessing it from multiple threads only for reading?  (myvector .size() .get() ...) For writing im using synchronized methods. Thank you.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

*Vector* is a thread-safe collection - all its methods are synchronized by default. This is why it's recommended to use *ArrayList* instead - it's not thread-safe which results in a better performance for single-thread applications.

Comment: Of course, ArrayList _is_ thread-safe if no thread ever writes the array after it has been _safely published_.  (But don't forget, "no thread" means, not even the _main_ thread.)

Comment: Why is there a difference for single thread applications? If there is never any other thread locking the `synchronized` methods, wouldn't it be virtually the same? Is there such an overhead for the `synchronized` mechanism added even without locking/blocking?

Answer (score 22):

As stated above, every single method of `Vector` is thread-safe by its own because of `synchronized` modifiers. But, if you need some complex operations, such as `get()` or `add()` based on condition which is related to the same `vector`, this is not thread-safe. See example below:

```
if (vector.size() > 0) {
    System.out.println(vector.get(0));
}
```

This code has a race condition between `size()` and `get()` - the size of vector might be changed by other thread after our thread verified the vector is not empty, and thus `get()` call may return unexpected results. To avoid this, the sample above should be changed like this:

```
synchronized (vector) {
    if (vector.size() > 0) {
        System.out.println(vector.get(0));
    }
}
```

Now this "get-if-not-empty" operation is atomic and race condition-free.

Answer (score 3):

The java.util.Vector methods are all synchronized. So using it from multiple threads is "safe". You only need to synchronize if you need a read-evaluate-write process to be atomic. Synchronizing your own methods does not necessarily make your code thread-safe for those scenarios. If the shared state is the Vector object, then you need to synchronize on the instance of your Vector, not on an instance of your own classes.

Comment: 'If the shared state is the Vector object, then you need to synchronize on the instance of your Vector', thanks that also helped me :)

Answer (score 1):

Vector class is thread safe (size, get, set methods are synchronized), but if you want to achieve better performance you should try to use `CopyOnWriteArrayList` or `Collections.synchronizedList` instead.